# for loop producing a lot of column names

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code to rename the columns of multiple dataframe, which works fine
but it is outputting stacked duplicated columns.

```
df_names=('castaways', 'challenge_description', 'challenge_results')
for df_name in df_names:
    df = globals()[df_name]
    df.columns = [df.columns.str.replace(' ','_').str.lower() for col_name in df.columns]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing up `df.columns.str.*` and list-comprehension. You need to do one or the other, but not both:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ','_').str.lower()
```

or

```
df.columns = [col_name.replace(' ','_').lower() for col_name in df.columns]
```